# How to use aws java sdk to retrieve accessKeyId, secretAccesskey and sessionToken?

Tags: amazon-web-services, sdk

our company have a Jenkins job, which need to input **accessKeyId**, **secretAccesskey** and **sessionToken** before build to production environment. However, developers need to follow a long long guideline to setup the aws client.. (and we cannot pull docker image from public repo)

do we have any method to build a spingboot web service, which just need developers input **email address** & **password** then return **accessKeyId**, **secretAccesskey** and **sessionToken**?

Comment: You need develop your own, custom solution for that.

Comment: @Marcin yes I know.. but how to do that

Answer (score 2):

You can use AWS Cognito service for this use-case. AWS Cognito generates temporary credentials which can have access to any AWS services defined/allowed by user (via policies).

If you want to use email address & password authentication then you can use identity pool and get the required secrets after authenticating your users.

A similar scenario is present in AWS Cognito documentation, maybe this suits your needs.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-scenarios.html#scenario-aws-and-user-pool

Comment: Thanks @Husyn .. but seems like this method need to create a new AWS service named AWS Cognito? And this may need infra role.. which we do not allow to do.